# How to ignore unused dll references in linqpad

Tags: c#, visual-studio, linqpad

I have an external dll (let's call it `A`) from a nuget package that also references another dll (let's call it `B`) whose functionality I don't need. I'm able to use dll `A` alone without issues in my own dll, when I do it in a console or web application built using the .net framework. However when I try to use my own dll in LinqPad I'm always faced with a "missing assembly" error, because it's trying to find `B`.

I cannot modify `A` as it is not mine, so is there a way I can tell LinqPad to ignore this indirect reference to `B`?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't add the NuGet package that provides A (which should also provide B from the same NuGet package or a dependency) to your LINQPad query via LINQPad?

Comment: Yes, there is, otherwise I would've done just that already. We are providing our own nuget, which depends on `A`. It is primarily used on some very complex web apps, which are having some serious conflicts with the dependencies on `B`, even though we really don't need anything from there. LinqPad is the only place that is complaining when we don't include `B`, though, the web apps and console apps work just fine without it.

Comment: The error occurs just when dumping objects with types from B, right?

Comment: No, the error occurs when dumping objects with types from `A`. But the error complains about missing the dll for `B`, I believe this is due to LinqPad trying to do some all or nothing reflection, but that's just my guess